# Defining a function given area under the curve, two points and rule for all points

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Given the integral of the function must equal $~15~$, and fit the points $~(0,0)~$ and $~(10,3)~$, the definite integral is between $~0~$ and $~10~$, *and* all points within this domain must adhere to $~y < 3.5~$, is it possible to define a function by adding one or more points and solving for their coordinates, or would trial and error be required?

The question says the area under the curve should be *approximately* $~15~$ units$^2~$, but I feel like there is a way to ensure it is exact, and just can't put my finger on it.

Comment: Sorry! I rephrased the question but I accidentally wrote invalid substitute numbers, I've edited the question to make it work now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By letting $y=f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ we can immediately see that $d=0$ as $f(0)=0$. Then, using the facts that $\int_0^{10}f(x)\mathrm{d}x=15$ and $f(10)=3$ we can solve for $a,b,c$. This gives us infinitely many solutions, so in order to generalise the solutions we can let $f(1)=k$ which gives
$$y=f(x)=\left(\frac1{36} k - \frac1{120}\right)x^3+\left(\frac18 -\frac5{12}k\right)x^2 + \left(\frac{25}{18}k - \frac7{60}\right)x$$
For example, if $k=1$ we get the solution
$$y=f(x)=\frac7{360}x^3-\frac7{24}x^2+\frac{229}{180}x$$
Note that in order for $y\lt3.5$ to be true $k$ must be restricted to the range
$$-0.46409\lt k\lt2.41009$$
approximately.

Comment: It would be, but the context of the question means that it must be a curve and not a linear function

Comment: @M.Davis See my edit.

Comment: Ah that's it! Thanks!

Comment: could you please explain how you eliminated a,b and c values to all be in terms of k? I have tried solving simultaneously on my calculator but getting no dice

Comment: I used Wolfram Alpha - see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=50%2F3+%28150+a+%2B+20+b+%2B+3+c%29%3D15+and+1000+a%2B100+b%2B10+c%3D3+and+a%2Bb%2Bc%3Dk+solve+for+a%2Cb%2Cc). The first equation comes from the integral being equal to $15$, the second equation equates to $f(10)=3$ and the third is $f(1)=k$.